# Bus error after converting big matrix to numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, large-data

I'm getting a straight out `Bus error (core dumped)` exit after attempting to resample a large matrix and convert it to a `numpy.array`.

Any pointers on how to do this efficiently and/or avoid the error would be appreciated.

Note that I'm running this on a node with 380Gb of memory.

Below is an example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random as rn

# matrix with zeros
zeros = np.zeros((594426, 16465))
# generate random indeces
random_idx = rn.sample(range(len(zeros)), len(zeros))
# set a limit based on the proportion of the test set
limit = int(len(zeros)*(1-0.2))

# indeces for random training and testing sets
random_train = random_idx[0:limit]
random_test = random_idx[limit:]

# subset original matrix
y_train = [zeros[i] for i in random_train]
y_test = [zeros[i] for i in random_test]

# convert to numpy array
y_train = np.array(y_train)
# error after this line
y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

Python version: 3.7.7

Numpy version: 1.17.0

Comment: I just checked and I'm not having this issue on Python version 3.7.1 with Numpy version 1.15.4

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be platform/system-dependent.